# Bash then sorting it

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Hey guys so i have this sample data from uniq-c:

```
100 c.m milk
99 c.s milk
45 cat food
30 beef
```

desired output:

```
beef,30
c.m milk,100
c.s milk,99
cat food,45
```

the thing i have tried are using:

```
awk -F " " '{print $2" " $3 " " $4 " " $5 "," $1}' stock.txt |sort>stock2.csv
```

i got :

```
beef   ,30
cat food
  ,45
c.m milk
  ,100
c.s milk
  ,99
```

think its because some item doesn't have 2,3,4,5 and i still use " ", and the sort in unix doesn't prioritise dot first unlike sql. however i'm not too sure how to fix it

Comment: On which system are you running this? From what I notice, i.e. the single line split into multiple lines, it seems like you have some special form of a carriage return or line feed in there. You see this as after every last word in the original file, a new line-feed appears with exception of the word "beef" as it is the last word in the file. What is the outcome of `file stock.txt` and could you try first to convert your file `stock.txt` to a unix file using `dos2unix stock.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain your desired output you could `sort` first your current input and then try to swap the columns.

Using `awk`, please give a try to this:

```
$ sort -k2 stock.txt | awk '{t=$1; sub($1 FS,""); print $0"," t}'
```

It will output:

```
beef,30
c.m milk,100
c.s milk,99
cat food,45
```

Comment: `sub($1 FS,"")` will fail when `$1` contains regexp metacharacters. Never use input data in a regexp context unless you have a specific purpose in mind that requires that.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can solve it in bash using some easy commands, if the format of the file is as you posted it:

prova.txt is your file.

then do:

```
cat prova.txt  | cut -d" " -f2,3 > first_col
cat prova.txt  | cut -d" " -f1 > second_col
paste -d "," first_col second_col | sort -u > output.csv
rm first_col second_col
```

in output.txt you have your desired output in CSV format!

EDIT:

after reading and applying PesaThe comment, the code is way easier:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d' ' -f2- prova.txt) <(cut -d' ' -f1 prova.txt) | sort -u > output.csv
```

Comment: You could use process substitution to avoid using temporary files: `paste -d, <(cut -d' ' -f2- data) <(cut -d' ' -f1 data)`.

Comment: didn't know this: it will make a lot of my code way easier!

Answer (score 2):

Combining additional information from [this](https://superuser.com/a/226489) thread with `awk`, the following script is a possible solution:

```
awk ' { printf "%s", $2; if ($3) printf " %s", $3; printf ",%d\n", $1; } ' stock.txt | LC_ALL=C sort > stock2.csv
```

It works well in my case. Nevertheless, I would prefer [nbari's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51946430/9818506) because it is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{$0=$0","$1; sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")} 1' file | LC_ALL=C sort
beef,30
c.m milk,100
c.s milk,99
cat food,45
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed + sort`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+(.+)/\2,\1/' file | C_ALL=C sort
```

```
beef,30
c.m milk,100
c.s milk,99
cat food,45
```

Comment: I suspect that this is locale-dependent, since I get `cat` before `c.m` if I use this.

Comment: Hmm may be `LC_ALL=C sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+(.+)/\2,\1/' file | sort` would be better

Comment: @anubhava Shouldn't you pass `LC_ALL=C` to `sort` instead of `sed`?